# Network monitoring across my lan

Tags: debian, networking, packet, traffic

I would like to monitor the network usage of all my deivces connected to same LAN network from raspberry pi 3. Since Pi3 is not a switch , it is also connected to the same network. Is it possible to monitor the other devices data usage. If yes please can you tell me the command to monitor the network usage of all the devices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An Ethernet switch learns the MAC addresses of all devices connected to it and then sends each packet to its destination port (or ports in case of multicast) only, unless it's broadcast. You can configure or trick your switch to not learn MAC addresses, so that every packet is broadcast (like by a hub), but the correct solution is to *ask* the switch for its traffic counters: run an SNMP data collector like Cricket or Cacti. I don't know what's easily available for Pi3, though.